# Consumer power over Ethernet

Tags: power-over-ethernet

Power over Ethernet has been around for years now, and is used in business and industrial settings, but I haven’t seen any good consumer PoE devices.

Am I not looking in the right places, or are PoE hubs/switches and PoE devices simply nonexistent in the consumer space?

Comment: Haven't seen hide nor hair of it in the consumer space.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can get PoE cameras. I think I have seen them at a surplus store before.

Answer (score 2):

I think consumer devices will go wi-fi instead, since once access point can pretty well cover an entire house.  Kinda hard to deliver power via wi-fi.

What I want to know is why there aren't more wi-fi enabled consumer electronics?

Comment: +1: Srsly.  Where the hell is my "Make Coffee" icon?

Comment: PAGING MR. TESLA, someone wants power-over-wireless. :-D

Answer (score 0):

I have wireless internet at my house. The wireless receiver is on my roof and is powered by PoE. The ethernet cable runs from inside the house, up to the receiver and that's how it gets the power.

That's the only use of PoE I've seen...

Comment: But that was a home-made PoE, right?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe the receiver is manufactured my Motorola. So unless my wireless provider 'customized' the unit for PoE then I don't think this is home-made.